# Store Data in a PHP Session to prevent too many MySQL-Connections

Tags: php, mysql, session

I recently started saving data that I use several times into a PHP session.

For example, I have to use the active countries for each load of the website. Instead of creating a database connection every time, I have now saved this data in a session. I do that with all the data that I use several times. I also created banners in a multi-level array and saved this array in a session.

On first Loading of the Website, all the data that i need, are collected and stored in several php session.

Now I have about 10 different PHP sessions at the start of the website but practically no database connection anymore.

Is this procedure workable in this way?
Do you see a risk? For me it's all about the performance of the site. I try to create as few database connections as possible for recurring tasks

Am I making a reasoning mistake?
There are no sensitive data in the session. For example, All Country for a  select field with all (necessary) countries. The array is then Key => Country. And so I create the Select field via "foreach".

Comment: By all means cache user-specific data in the session, but common data/resources should probably be put in an actual caching system so that it's computed and stored once, _period_. http://www.php-cache.com/en/latest/ I would say start off with the Filesystem cache and don't worry about setting up a cache server until you actually have evidence that you need to.

Comment: Also, unless you already have evidence that you're "making too many mysql connections" you should probably avoid spending too much time trying to address a problem that it's likely you're not even having, or that's better solved elsewhere in your code. https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/